# Alterando o Resultado de um <form> - Redirecionar para Outra Página no Envio

Tags: php, html

Olá,

Tenho um formulário e gostaria de saber como alterar os resultados dele.

Exemplo: tanto para quando o formulário for preenchido com sucesso quanto para quando aconteça algum erro ele redirecione para uma página de minha escolha.

Estou utilizando os seguinte código:

```
<form class="mbr-form" action="testeform@gmail.com" method="post" name="Meu Formulario">
      <div class="row row-sm-offset">
          <div class="col-md-4 multi-horizontal" data-for="name">
              <div class="form-group">
                   <label mbr-text class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style" mbr-theme-style="display-7" for="name">Nome</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" data-form-field="Name" required>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 multi-horizontal" data-for="email">
              <div class="form-group">
                   <label mbr-text class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style" mbr-theme-style="display-7" for="email">Email</label>
                   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" data-form-field="Email" required>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 multi-horizontal" data-for="phone" hidden="hidden">
              <div class="form-group">
                   <label mbr-text class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style" mbr-theme-style="display-7" for="phone" hidden="hidden">Produto</label>
                   <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" data-form-field="Phone" hidden="hidden">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" data-for="message">
          <label mbr-text class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style" mbr-theme-style="display-7" for="message">Mensagem</label>
          <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="message" rows="7" data-form-field="Message"></textarea>
      </div>

      <span mbr-buttons mbr-theme-style="display-4" data-toolbar="-mbrLink,-mbrBtnAdd,-mbrBtnMove" class="input-group-btn"><a href type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-form">ENVIAR MENSAGEM</a></span>
  </form>
```

Comment: O que pretende com esse código? Enviar os dados para o  email `testeform@gmail.com`?

Comment: Sim, exatamente. E após enviar os dados para o email, gostaria de direcionar o usuário para uma página externa (exemplo: www.google.com.br)

Comment: Tens suporte a php?

Comment: Esse formulário não tem suporte para php. Esse form foi criado com o Formoid (http://formoid.com)

Comment: Não conhecia esse formoid. O que eu quis perguntar é se o seu servidor tem PHP.

Comment: Sim, tem servidor PHP.

Comment: Porque phone é hidden?

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form class="mbr-form" action="" method="post" name="Meu Formulario">
  <div class="row row-sm-offset">
      <div class="col-md-4 multi-horizontal" data-for="name">
          <div class="form-group">
               <label mbr-text class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style" mbr-theme-style="display-7" for="name">Nome</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" data-form-field="Name" required>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 multi-horizontal" data-for="email">
          <div class="form-group">
               <label mbr-text class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style" mbr-theme-style="display-7" for="email">Email</label>
               <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" data-form-field="Email" required>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 multi-horizontal" data-for="phone" hidden="hidden">
          <div class="form-group">
               <label mbr-text class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style" mbr-theme-style="display-7" for="phone" hidden="hidden">Produto</label>
               <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" data-form-field="Phone" hidden="hidden">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" data-for="message">
      <label mbr-text class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style" mbr-theme-style="display-7" for="message">Mensagem</label>
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="message" rows="7" data-form-field="Message"></textarea>
  </div>

 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-form">
</form>
```

**Simples script de envio de email com PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $to = "seuMail@seuDominio.com";
  $subject = "Form";
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email= $_POST['email'];
  /********o input phone está hidden *******/
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";

    if(mail($to, $subject, $body)){
       header('Location: http://www.google.com.br');
    }else{
       echo "Erro no envio";
    }
}
```

> Um bom script de envio de email é o  PHPMailer

```
    /******* CODIGO EMAIL *******/

    /* Uma dica para envio de emails
    Baixe os arquivos  PHPMailerAutoload.php - class.smtp.php -  class.phpmailer.php
    em github - https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable
    Crie uma pasta  PHPMailer-master no mesmo diretório da sua aplicação PHP e 
    publique os arquivos baixados nesta pasta (PHPMailer-master).
    */
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {    

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $celular = $_POST['phone'];

    $mensagem = $_POST['message'];

    //email Destinatario
    $emailDest = "nome@dominio.com";

    $email = Trim(str_replace("'","",$email));


    require_once 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.dominio.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = 'username@dominio.com';
    $mail->Password = 'senha';

    //$mail->SMTPSecure = false; //Diz que nao tem tls/ssl
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
    //$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; //Diz que nao tem tls/ssl

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //Mostra os bugs

    //E-mail remetente
    $mail->From = $email;

    //Nome do remetente
    $mail->FromName = $nome;

    //Assunto da mensagem
    $mail->Subject = "teste mail";

    //Corpo da mensagem
    $mail->Body = "Celular ".$phone." - Mensagem ".$mensagem;

    //Corpo da mensagem em texto
    //$mail->AltBody = 'Conteudo do e-mail em texto';


    //Destinatario 
    $mail->AddAddress ($emailDest);

    $mail->Send();

}
```